# Set a default form backgroundimage in Visual Studio WYSIWYG editor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

**Context**

- Viusal Studio 2019, Windows 11
- .NET 5.0
- Winforms Project

I have a VB.NET application with 3 form backgroundimage depending on working environment (Production, Integration, and Test).

I set this backgroundimage at application start when users choose the working environment and I store the backgroundimage in a public variable ```imgBackgroundFormUsed````

In the form designers, i set the background image for the forms and its controls using this variable, e.g:
`Me.grpCorpusMetaDatas.BackgroundImage = imgBackgroundFormUsed`

**Problem**

in Visual Studio, WYSIWIG form editor, the background image is set to None and the edition become pretty lame, considering that i set controls forecolor to white

**Question**

Is there anyway to set some kind of default background image in the Visual Studio WYSIWIG form editor, only for this particular project ?
I could set the appropriate backgroundimage when forms load but it would add lots of codes.

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. Can't you embed an image and set it as the `BackgroundImage` of your Form in the Designer? Or save this setup as Template, if you need to give it to others?

Comment: I dont know how to be more precise.
I have no problem to set an image as the backgroundImage or to make this image be variable (depending on an user choice) but in the WYSIWYG editor, it made the form not easy to edit (because there is no background image as the background is a variable set on running time)

Comment: Well, you can be way more clear. The *user choice*, as you mentioned, is a Run-Time selection. In the Form Designer (hence at Design-Time), set the `BackgroundImage` to an embedded Bitmap (from the Project's Resources), which acts as the *default* background. Change it at Run-Time to anything else -- If this is not the scenario, then explain what that is.